# unable to send the mail using objective c?

Tags: objective-c

i am very new to objective c.i am trying to send the email whenever the user clicks the  send button.whenever i clicks the button the if condition is not satisfied and coming out of the loop also the email is not send.

This is my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
@interface complaintsviewcontroller : UITableViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

This is my .m file

```
- (IBAction)sendbutton:(id)sender {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
    NSString *emailTitle = @"Test Email";
    // Email Content
    NSString *messageBody = @"testing ";
    // To address
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"noreply@etowns.in"];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller   didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

can anyone suggest me what is the mistake i done in the above coding ?

Comment: you can share the specific error you getting ..

Comment: Check whether in device any mail is configured in Apple Mail app or not!

Comment: i am not getting error .i set the break point and checked when i click the button it will come out of the loop(if condition is not satisfied)

Comment: @hament miglani thanks for ur reply sir. my device is not configured with any mail

Comment: if i took that if condition i am getting the following exception" Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <complaintsviewcontroller: 0x1592181b0>." and app getting crashed

Comment: You won't be able to send email from Simulator. You can only check this functionality on iOS device with any account configured in Mail application

Comment: i am checking in real device only sir

Comment: Then did you configured Mail application  with any account?

Comment: @user19, sure it will crash without the condition. Just check my ans, wait a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the standards you need to check *`MFMailComposeViewController` is able to send your mail just before sending* using below condition.

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
     // configure your email part here 
     // if not checking, this misleads the standards or leads uncertainty further  
}
```

After that if you have not configured mail **Mail Accounts** under the **`settings -> mail`**, an alert appears like below.

[image]

**Final Solution:** If you got something like above popup just [configure the mail account](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201320) with *gmail, yahoo* or anyone, so the mailcomposer will be able to send email on behalf.

Comment: thank u very sir it's working but i have another doubt can we able to send the email without registering the email address in our mobile phone

Comment: @user19 no its not legal to do soo, actually apple 's iPhone is sending mail to someone which cannot be a spam it should be sent on someone's behalf. If you do so, maybe your app will likely to reject.

Comment: you can do this by using web services by sending them appropriate params but not using native functionality of Apple.